# Using Python's `in`-operator in Pandas dataframe .loc

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm working with a some Pandas dataframes and I can't quite get why some boolean operators are allowed and work in the `.loc`-selector and others give an error. To be precise, let's take the following dataframe:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': 'foo bar foo bar foo bar foo foo'.split(),
                   'B': 'one one two thr two two one thr'.split()})
```

Now both `'two' == 'two'` and `'w' in 'two'` evaluate as `True`, but when used with `df.loc[...]` the following works:

```py
df.loc[df['B'] == 'two']
```

printing out

```
         A       B
    2   foo     two
    4   foo     two
    5   bar     two
```

But the following raises a `KeyError: False` -error.

```py
df.loc['w' in df['B']]
```

I know ways to work around this, but none of them feel particularly smooth, and even worse I don't understand at all why the `'w' in df['B']` -selector is not allowed in `.loc`.

Comment: `'w' in df['B'] ` returns only one outcome True or False; does not care about for which index it is True or False. `.loc[]` requires indices of the data frame but with that you are not passing any index into it so it throws an error. Most likely you get  KeyError.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at the output of `df['B'] == 'two` and compare it to the output of `'w' in df['B']`. The first one will output a panda Series containing either True or False for each row in `df['B']`. The second one will output `False`.

The `.loc` operator can take "A boolean array of the same length as the axis being sliced, e.g. [True, False, True]" (see [.loc documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)). You obtain the `KeyError: False` because `.loc` tries to find `False` which is neither a column nor a row name.

To use the `w in df['B']`-expression you could do:

```py
list_true_false = ['w' in entry for entry in df['B']]`

df.loc[list_true_false]`
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 3):

You need the isin operator or the contains function

1. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html
2. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html

```
df.loc[df['B'].isin(['two'])] # to match the full word specify it as list
df.loc[df['B'].str.contains('w')] # to match the pattern or a letter
```